# Crystal Reports: Sumatorias condicionales

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

¿Cómo se puede sumar ciertos registros que cumplan una condición dinámica? Por ejemplo, el usuario con `"ID" = 1` de la tabla `"Usuario"` tiene tres compras en la tabla `"Compras"`. Esta tabla `"Compras"` tiene tres campos: `ID_Compra`, `ID_Usuario` y `Monto_Compra`. ¿Cómo hago en Crystal Reports para poder sumar estas tres únicas compras, si en mi tabla existen más de 200 clientes y más de mil compras? ¿Cómo puedo agrupar sus compras y no hacer una sumatoria de todos los campos de la tabla?

Estoy usando la siguiente fórmula:

```
sum({Compras.Monto_Compra})
```

Esta fórmula me suma las más de mil compras de la tabla `Compras`. Veo que Crystal Reports tiene la opción de sumas condicionales, pero no he encontrado ejemplos de uso.

Comment: No se entiende bien cual es la condición para la suma.

Answer (score 1):

Si se trata de sumar los montos de los diferentes Usuarios, entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es **crear un grupo por ID_Usuario** y pasarlo a la función SUM como segundo parámetro:

```
sum({Compras.Monto_Compra},{Compras.ID_Usuario})
```

---

### Actualizado

También es posible sumar solamente los montos del Usuario con "ID_Usuario = 1" (si a eso te referías con "*para poder sumar estas tres únicas compras*").
En Fórmulas de selección de registros agregar la siguiente:

```
{Compras.ID_Usuario} = 1
```