# Suma condicional en Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Estoy trabajando con Crystal Report desde Visual Studio 2017, me pidieron hacer una suma que agrupara, tengo 3 opciones: Notas de Credito, Boleta y Factura.

Lo primero que hice fue crear un Campo de Fórmula con el nombre **NumberValorCif** para convertir el ValorCIF que tengo a numérico con **ToNumber()**. Esto lo guardado y creo otro campo de formula con nombre **SumCIFCredito** que tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
If {CobroPorcentaje.TipoDoc} = 'Notas de Credito'
then {@NumberValorCif}
else 0
```

Guardé, compilé e hice correr la aplicación y funcionó sin ningún problema... pero. Quise hacer lo mismo para **SumCIFBoleta**:

```
If {CobroPorcentaje.TipoDoc} = 'Boleta'
then {@NumberValorCif}
else 0
```

Pero no me suma nada. ¿Me falta algo? o tengo que crear otra variable.

Ojalá alguien me pueda ayudar.

aclaro que probé esta solución [LINK1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26583/crystal-reports-sumatorias-condicionales) pero no me funcionó

Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Y si mandas ese dato listo? Es decir, que lo proceses antes de mandarlo al Crystal Report y que Crystal sólo renderize la data que hay. ¿Has intentado?

Comment: sinceramente no, estaba pegado con que tenía que hacerlo con crystal. Gracias por la idea

Comment: Vale, con cariño hermano, estamos para servir, esta comunidad es muy particular, las ideas vuelan y todos progresamos, cada vez mejores oportunidades para todos :D

Comment: hey bro! ¿lograste hacerlo funcionar en esta semana que ha pasado?

Answer (score 1):

Parece que simplemente necesita agregar la SUMA real de esa nueva fórmula.

Coloque la nueva fórmula en la sección de detalles, selecciónela, presione el botón Sigma para sumarla y elija generar subtotales para su agrupar por nivel.